# How to read string containing any ASCII character in Java?

Tags: java, string, character, ascii

The code below should simply echo the input. Instead, the output is different than the input.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    }

}
```

Example input: `$$$$$abcd$$$$$`
Expected output: `$$$$$abcd$$$$$`
Actual output: `6666$`

Can anyone please help me with my code if anything is wrong in this?

Comment: Could be a problem on your computer, if you don't have the glyphs (characters) needed to display then you might get substitutions in the output.  This is beyond Java's control.  Or you might be putting characters in the input that Java doesn't understand.  What input do you give it?

Comment: Uhm, that would have to be a 'serious encoding issue' to get such a difference.. how is the data being supplied? Maybe the input example/expectation is incorrect?

Comment: Although wrt. encoding, perhaps that would be good to check - the default can change; Attempting to read in "ANSI" - ["Extended ASCII"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) is *not* [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), ASCII is 7-bit clean - as UTF-8, for example, may lead to surprising results as UTF-8 will treat byte values 128-255 differently..

Comment: @Kapoor I edited you question slightly to try and make it a little clearer what you were inputting, what you output you were expecting, and what output you're actually getting. Please, let me know if I changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: Did you try to specify the charset ? Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "ASCII");

Comment: @markspace I tried running this on online compiler also but it gave the same output don't know why.